# Which dropdown plug in to use in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropdownbox

Following are the requirements of Search panel in my MVC application:

1. I need three dropdowns (or list boxes) - Countries, States, and
   Cities
2. **Multiple selection** should be possible in each of these
   dropdowns.
3. **Autocomplete** is also required.
4. There is a WCF service which interacts which performs DB operations
   aimed to build data sources for these dropdowns.
5. When user selects a Country, it should populate list of States, and
   Cities. (there shouldn't be anything in States and Cities data
   source unless a Country is not selected)
6. There shouldn't be anything in Countries data source unless a user
   first clicks on "Search panel". This is to avoid data transfer from
   server to client unless it's requested.

This means, I need to heavily rely on JQuery, and AJAX.

Any idea what could be the best plug in to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found select2 more suitable to my requirements